# Use frozenset as a pair in python

Tags: python, set, immutability

I would like to make a pair of two elements. I don't care about the order of the elements, so I use  `frozenset`.

I can think of the following two methods to iterate the elements back from the frozenset. Isn't there any fancier method? Thanks in advance.

```
pair = frozenset([element1, element2])
pair2 = list(pair)
elem1 = pair2[0]
elem2 = pair2[1]
```

```
pair = frozenset([element1, element2])
elems = []
for elem in pair:
    elems.append(elem)
elem1 = elems[0]
elem2 = elems[1]
```

Comment: Seems like you're already iterating over the elements in pair with `for elem in pair`. Is there something more you want?

Comment: `frozenset` might also be confusing when the two elements in the pair are identical. Then there won't be a pair at all -- we will have a frozenset consisting of a single element, and your code will break with `IndexError`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
pair = frozenset([element1, element2])
elem1, elem2 = pair
```

Comment: This must be what he means. +1

Comment: @kindall: +1 Never knew one could unpack sets like this! Side note: it might not be unreasonable to mention that tuples are probably just as efficient...

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why he's not just using a tuple. But unpacking works with any sequence -- even an iterator, in fact.

Comment: Tuple keeps ordering information, whereas set or frozenset doesn't keep the information. Both (x, y) and (y, x) should be equal in my problem.

Comment: Yeah, equality's a good reason. I'll put that in my bag of tricks. :-)

Comment: @kindall, @tomowind: Consider **sorted** tuples -- see my answer.

Comment: What happens when there is only one element in the frozenset?  Should we convert to a list and use index to unpack or is there a better way?

Comment: You can do `a, = seq` (note the comma after `a`) to unpack a single-item sequence, but `seq[0]` is probably clearer. Or `next(iter(seq))` if it's not an indexable type.

Answer (score 9):

If you have a lot of those pair things, using `frozenset()` is NOT a good idea. Use tuples instead.

```
>>> import sys
>>> fs1 = frozenset([42, 666])
>>> fs2 = frozenset([666, 42])
>>> fs1 == fs2
True
>>> t1 = tuple(sorted([42, 666]))
>>> t2 = tuple(sorted([666, 42]))
>>> t1 == t2
True
>>> sys.getsizeof(fs1)
116
>>> sys.getsizeof(t1)
36
>>>
```

*Update* Bonus: sorted tuples have a predictable iteration sequence:

```
>>> for thing in fs1, fs2, t1, t2: print [x for x in thing]
...
[42, 666]
[666, 42]
[42, 666]
[42, 666]
>>>
```

*Update 2* ... and their repr() is the same:

```
>>> repr(fs1)
'frozenset([42, 666])'
>>> repr(fs2)
'frozenset([666, 42])' # possible source of confusion
>>> repr(t1)
'(42, 666)'
>>> repr(t2)
'(42, 666)'
>>>
```

Comment: Since tuples are immutable, you could easily create a `tuple` subclass that sorts in the `__init__()` method. Nice trick.

Comment: Actually, it'd have to be in `__new__()` not `__init__()` (since tuples are immutable, they aren't initialized in `__init__()`). Just tried it; it worked great.

Comment: It looks like a very nice trick! But, when applying this trick to my code, the program works a bit slower. (I don't know why. I would like to create a code snippet for my code and analyze again. I will post another thing later.)  Thank you very much anyways!!

Comment: Just curious, ran across this answer and wondering why using frozensets is a bad idea. Is it just because of how much memory they take up?

Comment: Oh right, got it. Since the original poster stated he didn't care about the order of elements didn't even occur to me that predictable order was a feature.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just two elements you are de-sequence them. But I am not sure, what you are trying to do here with the frozenset

```
>>> s = frozenset([1,2])
>>> s
frozenset({1, 2})
>>> x,y = s
>>> x
1
>>> y
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on an above [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189909/use-frozenset-as-a-pair-in-python/5191319#comment5840432_5191319), and assuming your elements are easily sortable, you could make an unordered pair class from `tuple` using:

```
class Pair(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, seq=()):
        assert len(seq) == 2
        return tuple.__new__(tuple, sorted(seq))
```

Then you get:

```
>>> Pair((0, 1))
(0, 1)

>>> Pair((1, 0))
(0, 1)

>>> Pair((0, 1)) == Pair((1, 0))
True
```