# Hashing frozenset versus tuple of sorted

Tags: python, hash, python-3.x

In Python, given a set of comparable, hashable elements `s`, is it better to hash `frozenset(s)` or `tuple(sorted(s))`.

Comment: Related topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189909/use-frozenset-as-a-pair-in-python

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you are doing. It is faster to create a `frozenset()` than to sort a `tuple`, but `frozenset` takes up more memory than a `tuple`.

It is faster to create a `frozenset` than a `tuple`:

```
import timeit

import random as rn

x = range(2000)
rn.shuffle(x)
x = tuple(x)

def get_frozen_set(x):
    return frozenset(x)

def get_sorted_tuple(x):
    return sorted(x)

n = 10000

t1 = timeit.timeit('get_frozen_set(x)', 'from __main__ import x, get_frozen_set', number = n)
print 'create a frozenset:', t1
t2 = timeit.timeit('get_sorted_tuple(x)','from __main__ import x, get_sorted_tuple', number = n)
print 'sort tuple:', t2
```

Result:

```
create a frozenset: 0.85803164112
sort tuple: 6.65848886198
```

Although the difference is let very big for starting `tuple` is short. For `n = 20`

Result:

```
create a frozenset: 0.0124568308591
sort tuple: 0.0257906431368
```

`frozenset` takes up more `memory`, this is illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189909/use-frozenset-as-a-pair-in-python).

There is a very small difference in look up time between `frozenset` and `tuple`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398470/is-there-a-performance-difference-in-using-a-tuple-over-a-frozenset-as-a-key-for)

Comment: thanks for your answer.  first of all, you're starting with a list whereas I'm starting with a set.  Second, I'm also interested if the frozenset's hash function's order invariance will mean better hash values.

Comment: @NeilG, I am looking at `tuples`, `x` in my case is a `tuple`, but I get very similar results when I look at `lists`. What exactly do you mean by better hash values? If you already created a dictionary, look up time difference between dictionary with `frozensets` and keys and `tuples` as keys is small.