# Python list withing list distinct elements

Tags: python, list

I have a list that looks like this:

```
a = [[99 , 2],[2,99]]
```

My objective is to get a list that has one of the elements because they are similar combinations:

so I need another list b that is either:

```
b = [[99,2]]
```

or

```
b= [[2,99]]
```

How do I go about it in the most efficient manner without any libraries, answers with libraries are also appreciated since I would wanna know what are the stuffs already out there to ease my pain with learning how to code.

Thank you

Comment: I would like to remove all the other combinations. Just need one of the elements.

Comment: if your sublist don't contain duplicates, you can transform them into frozenset, then pass that into a set and you get the one that are different, but if you only need to pick one because they are just permutation of a set of elements, just arbitrarily pick one

Comment: Needs a description of how your list looks in general. For example whether the sublists always have two Elena's, whether they always differ, whether always both (all?) orders occur. And if not all orders occur, whether the order on the output matters.

Answer (score 3):

There might be many different ways to do it, but one option is to use `frozenset` in `set`:

```py
a = [[99,2],[1,2,3],[2,99],[2,3,1]]
b = set(frozenset(x) for x in a) # alternatively, set(map(frozenset, a))
print(b) # {frozenset({1, 2, 3}), frozenset({2, 99})}
b = [list(x) for x in b]
print(b) # [[1, 2, 3], [2, 99]]
```

Another option is to use (sorted) tuples to represent the "uniquified" elements:

```py
b = set(tuple(sorted(x)) for x in a)
```

However, `frozenset` seems faster: [Hashing frozenset versus tuple of sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534495/hashing-frozenset-versus-tuple-of-sorted)

Comment: If you want fast, then don't reimplement `map`.

Comment: @KellyBundy Can you give me more details? I am afraid I am not experienced to understand it. Please teach me, thanks.

Comment: I mean better use map instead of your generator expression.

Comment: @KellyBundy Aha now I understand, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I can give you an answer using libraries. `random` is part of the python standard library (you already have it installed if you have python), so depending on why you don't want to use libraries, this might work.

```
import random

a = [[99 , 2],[2,99]]
b = random.choice(a)
```

`b` will be a list that has exactly one of the elements of list `a`.
If you need `b` to be a list of lists, modify it like so:

```
import random

a = [[99 , 2],[2,99]]
b = [random.choice(a)]
```

Comment: What even is this answer? He is not asking to peek random. He is asking how to distinct them

Comment: @sudden_appearance what even is this comment